# file downloading in cakephp 1.3

Tags: download, cakephp-1.3

I use the code for downloading an image from directort that is outside of webroot but it is not work.
Here's my controller code:

```
public function download() {


$this->autoRender = false;
        $this->view = 'Media';
        $type = explode('.',$this->params['pass'][1]);
        // Download app/outside_webroot_dir/example.zip
        $params = array(
            'id'        => $this->params['pass'][1],
            'name'      => $this->params['pass'][0],
            'download'  => true,
            'extension' => $type[1],
            'path'      => APP . 'media' . DS .'DealMenu'. DS . $this->params['pass'][0]. DS . $this->params['pass'][1]
        );
        $this->set($params);
    }
```

Comment: can you post the errors?

Comment: there are not any errors and nothing happend